# How to check if scrollbar of an edit control is at the bottom?

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @immibis, I can now scroll to the bottom of the control successfully using `WM_VSCROLL`, but I still want to know how you can check if the scrollbar is at the bottom.

I have a read-only edit control:

```
HWND hMsgDisplay = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY | WS_VSCROLL, 10, 10, 664, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MESSAGE_DISPLAY_EDIT, hInst, NULL);
```

And I want to scroll to the bottom of it. I have been trying this:

```
SCROLLINFO sb;
ZeroMemory(&sb, sizeof(sb));
sb.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO);
sb.fMask = SIF_ALL;
GetScrollInfo(hMsgDisplay, SB_VERT, &sb);
while (abs(sb.nMax - sb.nPos) > 1) {
    SendMessage(hMsgDisplay, EM_SCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, NULL);
    GetScrollInfo(hMsgDisplay, SB_VERT, &sb);
}
```

It worked fine when there's only one or two lines of text in the edit control, but after that the program enters an infinite loop and gets stuck. I debugged it and found out that even when the scrollbar is gray (it's there but it cannot be scrolled), the `sb.nMax` still gives me a non-zero number, and no matter how many times I send the `EM_SCROLL` message, `sb.nPos` remains 0. How can I detect that the scrollbar has been scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: MSDN says sending EM_SCROLL is equivalent to sending WM_VSCROLL, and WM_VSCROLL has a SB_BOTTOM option. Did you try sending that instead, once, to scroll to the bottom straight away?

Comment: Alternatively, use [`SetScrollPos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787597.aspx) or [`SetScrollInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595.aspx) (since you already know the max position from `GetScrollInfo()`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @immibis! I just tried it and it worked. Sorry about not looking it up first before posting this question... But even though this is solved, I still want to know how you can check if scrollbar is at the bottom.

Comment: `nPage` tells you how big a page is; if `nMax` is less than a size of a page it can't scroll at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for check the bottom position use this code

```
BOOL IsBotomPos(HWND hwnd)
{
    SCROLLINFO si = {sizeof(si), SIF_ALL};

    if (GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si))
    {
        return si.nPos + si.nPage == (UINT)si.nMax + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

so condition is `si.nPos + si.nPage == (UINT)si.nMax + 1;`

this is also return `true` for empty edit or scroll not active yet (in this case `nPos == 0` and `nPage == nMax + 1` )

for scroll to bottom you can simply call

`SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);`

despite use `SB_BOTTOM` with [`EM_SCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761635(v=vs.85).aspx) undocumented, it work in my test

if you want smooth scroll - you can use next code:

```
void DoSmoothScroll(HWND hwnd, BOOL byPage)
{
    SCROLLINFO si = {sizeof(si), SIF_ALL};

    if (GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si))
    {
        int n = si.nMax + 1 - si.nPage - si.nPos;

        if (0 < n)
        {
            if (byPage && si.nPage)
            {
                n = (n + si.nPage - 1) / si.nPage;
                LONG r = MAKELONG(si.nPage - 1, TRUE);
                do 
                {
                    if (SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN, 0) != r)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                } while (--n);
            }
            else
            {
                do 
                {
                    if (SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0) != MAKELONG(1, TRUE))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                } while (--n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

your also can combine - first try fast scroll with "undocumented" `SB_BOTTOM`, then check are we really scrolled, and if not - try smooth scroll

```
void ScrollEx(HWND hwnd)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);
    DoSmoothScroll(hwnd, TRUE);
}
```

really in function `DoSmoothScroll`

`int n = si.nMax + 1 - si.nPage - si.nPos;`

must be 0 if `SB_BOTTOM` worked and we just exit, without additional scrolling

Comment: @Tyler - I extend code of `DoSmoothScroll` - add option select - scroll by page or by line